# Opendaylight OSGI System bundles went down automatically when node is Quarantined

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, opendaylight

We are using Nitrogen version of ODL and we are trying 2 node cluster. During our testing we observed following

1. Split brain between the nodes.
2. Akka actor on each node quarantined their peer.
3. After quarantining, System bundle were stopped automatically and all dependent bundles were also stopped and restarted.

We noticed following code is getting triggered when nodes are quarantined. Please refer to apply() in 
[ActorSystemProvider Source Code](https://github.com/qqbbyq/controller/blob/master/opendaylight/md-sal/sal-distributed-datastore/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/controller/config/yang/config/actor_system_provider/impl/ActorSystemProviderImpl.java)

Could you please answer following queries

1. Reason for shutting down system bundles and also why are we doing it in both the nodes.

> bundleContext.getBundle(0).stop();

2. Is it possible to **disable** shutdown and restart of system bundles.

Answer (score 3):

When akka quarantines a node, it won't let it back in the cluster until the actor system is restarted. That essentially means restarting ODL hence we restart the karaf container. It's quirky but unfortunately that is the way akka is designed and works so there's no other choice (at least not that I know of).

Comment: Thanks Tom Pantelis for your prompt responses.

Comment: @satlearner you should mark as answered and upvote, if this answer works for you.